# t-sql reordering rows

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a column called "Priority".  No two records should have the same priority value.

If I add a new entry with the same priority value as an existing record, it should increment the

priority of the other records that follow IF the previous row's increment causes a duplicate priority.

For example:

We want to insert a record with a priority of 2.

(BEFORE)
priority
 1
 2
 3
 5

(AFTER)
Priority
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

Another example:

Insert a record with a priority of 2

(BEFORE)
priority
 1
 2
 3
 5
 7

(AFTER)
Priority
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 7

I am doing this with the following code and it works as long as there are no gaps in sequence:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Priority = Priority + 1 
WHERE LocationId = @LocationId AND Priority >= @priorityToInsert
```

The problem is that this update statement increments ALL priority values.  Example #2 above fails

because the record with priority 7 gets incremented to 8 when it shouldn't.

Please help!

Comment: If you continue using this method keep an eye on performance...  You are potentially updating every record in this table every time you insert a new one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a tag indicating the database you're using.  The answer may differ depending on the DB and version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable t1
SET t1.Priority = t1.Priority + 1 
WHERE t1.LocationId = @LocationId 
AND t1.Priority >= @priorityToInsert 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE t2.LocationId = @LocationId
        AND t2.Priority = t1.Priority - 1
)
```

The problem is that if you also had an 8 in your case, it WOULD advance the 8 to 9 because it sees the 7, even though the 7 wouldn't advance.

Because it's recursive like this, you would probably have to use a recursive or iterative technique.

I would think about a different design or perhaps something with triggers.